# How to change the precision while creating an HLL Sketch using Big Query's SQL Editor in GCP?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a sketch as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions#hll_countinit).

But I want to change the precision of my sketch. I tried modifying the example given in the documentation in this way:

```
SELECT
  HLL_COUNT.INIT(respondent [, 14]) AS respondents_hll,
  flavor,
  country
FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(1 AS respondent, "Vanilla" AS flavor, "CH" AS country),
  (1, "Chocolate", "CH"),
  (2, "Chocolate", "US"),
  (2, "Strawberry", "US")])
GROUP BY flavor, country;
```

But it shows an error `Syntax error: Unexpected "," at [2:30]`

How do I change the precision? I can't find any examples for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see the function signature:

[image]

- The brackets means that the `precision` is optional;
- It must be between `10` and `24`;
- the documentation is quite bad, open a feature request to fix it:

`HLL_COUNT.INIT(input [, precision])` should be `HLL_COUNT.INIT(input, [precision])`

You should use the following:

```sql
SELECT
  HLL_COUNT.INIT(respondent,14) AS respondents_hll,
  flavor,
  country
FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(1 AS respondent, "Vanilla" AS flavor, "CH" AS country),
  (1, "Chocolate", "CH"),
  (2, "Chocolate", "US"),
  (2, "Strawberry", "US")])
GROUP BY flavor, country;
```